# Java - Reading text file

Tags: java, regex, text-files, bufferedreader

I have a text file as follow:

```
Past Dues / Refunds / Subsidy
Arrears / Refunds
Amount
2013.23
Period to which
it  relates
Since OCT-15
```

Now, how do I extract the data in the next line of "Amount".
I have tried it using boolean, checking the above and below line.

Is there any other way to do it.

My code:

```
boolean isGroup=false;
while(line = br.readline() != null){
    if(line.equals("Amount"){
      isGroup=true;
    }
    if(line.equals("Period to which") && isGroup)
      isGroup=false;
    if(isGroup){
      //read line and check whether it is null or not
      String amount = line;
    }
 }
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: So you tried by using a boolean and checking the above line. That should work. What is your issue with that method? Why do you want a different method? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: theres nothing wrong with that method why whats the problem ?

Comment: @nhouser9  see my code in the question. It is too long, as I have too much data to be extracted. Is there any shorter way?

Comment: @Priyamal I am looking for a shorter method, where I can directly read the next line to "Amount".

Comment: You read the line with `Amount`, then set `isGroup`, and then assign the line to `amount` in the `if` before next line is read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine.  You made a little mistake by setting the boolean, then using on the same iteration of the loop.

If you do the following you should be fine:

```
String amount = "No amount found";
boolean isGroup=false;
while(line = br.readline() != null) {
    // Check all your conditions to see if this is the line you care about
    if(isGroup){
      amount = line;
      isGroup = false; // so you only capture this once
      continue;
    }
    else if (isOtherCondition) {
      // handle other condition;
      isOtherCondition = false; // so you only capture this once
      continue;
    }

    // Check the contents of lines to see if it's one you want to read next iteration
    if(line.equals("Amount"){
      isGroup=true;
    }
    else if (line.equals("Some Other Condition")) {
      isOtherCondition = true;
    }
 }
```

This is all you need.  The `break;` is just so you don't have to worry about what happens after you grab the amount.

Comment: `break;` will take me out of the while loop, what if my loop also contains some other tasks as well. Can I use `continue;` to jump to next line iteration?

Comment: Yeah... let me update the answer so you can do other tasks.

Comment: for example, I want to extract the line next to "Amount" as well as the next line to "it  relates".

Comment: Sorry to bother you, can you write the previous code as well?

Comment: I think our comments collided... do you want both versions of the code I wrote?  You should be able to see the original code I posted by clicking "edited [n] mins ago" and see a side-by-side comparison of the original code and the new code (if that doesn't work out I can rewrite the original approach)

Comment: Got it! Thank You.

Comment: @Dax - For this kind of line-examining code it is hard to maintain. The series of bool's you have to use makes it convoluted. I understand you don't know regex, but regex is perfect for a form type extraction.

Comment: @sln Yes I am not so much familiar with regrex in java. Anyways Thank you.

Comment: Regex could be the way to go here, but I think it very much depends on the entire file you're reading in, how consistent the format is etc.  If you have to write a regex that matches the entire file to extract different sections... the whole thing is massively unmaintainable.  Obviously a gigantic set of booleans isn't maintainable either unless you're only extracting two or three lines.

Comment: @xbakesx - `have to write a regex that matches the entire file to extract different ` No, no, not true at all..

Comment: I need to extract six lines, I think I can manage with boolean approach. I am not so aware about regrex.

Comment: @Dax - If your file contains records, you'd write a regex for a single record then you'd end up with an array of structures with each records data. This is not something you'd really attempt with a line based solution. I mean given all the variant input usually associated with field data, some there some not, some empty, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

If the file is average size, you could use a regex.
Just read in the entire file into a string.
To use a regex it would be something like this.
Result is in capture group 1.

`"(?mi)^\\s*Amount\\s+^\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)\\s*$"`

```
 (?mi)                     # Multi-line mode, case insensitive
 ^                         # Beginning of line
 \s* Amount \s+ 
 ^                         # Beginning of line 
 \s* 
 (                         # (1 start), Numeric value
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )                         # (1 end)
 \s* 
 $                         # End of line
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how can I use this regrex?

Comment: @dax see my answer above based on sln's regex

Comment: @Dax - Google Java regex. I think you could just read the file into a string, then run a `FindAll` or `Match` and it will return an array of values. I don't use Java regex, but I write them all the time. This could be fleshed out to get more values of a record, but more into is needed on the record structure.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you would do @sln answer in java

```
String text = "Past Dues / Refunds / Subsidy\n" +
"Arrears / Refunds\n" +
"Amount\n" +
"2013.23\n" +
"Period to which\n" +
"it  relates\n" +
"Since OCT-15";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?mi)^Amount\\s(?<amount>\\d+\\.\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher =  pattern.matcher(text);

if(matcher.find()){
  String amount = matcher.group("amount");
  System.out.println("amount: "+ amount);
}
```

Comment: Nice. I like the short numeric part too.